# How to use a stored procedure from SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6.1

I have a ASP.NET MVC5 project with EF6. In SQL server 2008 I have a stored procedure that takes 2 parameters, an ID and a language ID, and returns data based on the parameters.

I want to call this stored procedure in one of my controllers to view the data. But I don't know how to do this. Can anybody help me or provide a tutorial for it?

I have the stored procedure in the project as an ADO.NET entity object already, it has a model class and such thus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Entity Framework's `ExecuteSqlCommand` to achieve this:

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@param1", "Item1");
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@param2", "Item2");

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "sp_StoredProcedureName @param1, @param2",
    param1,
    param2);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll be testing this now.